# Elastic search Spring

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a problem with configure elastic search using spring. I am using elastic search 6.2.3. All time i have a trouble with connect spring with elastic search "server".

First i open elasticsearch.bat

Here is my configuration:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.abc.portal.City")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.portal.City"})
public class ElasticConfig {

Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("node.name","node-1").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
Client client;


public ElasticConfig(){
    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9300)));
}
  }
```

About settings, i get properties name from elasticsearch.YML:

```
  Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
```

And in the end i create prop in application.properties:

```
 spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
 spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

My error is:

```
 failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{nMDmllJPQPitdDD8IEPKMA}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Provide port as 9200 or specify in your `Settings.builder.put`